# SQL: inner join on alias column

Tags: sql, inner-join

Previously I have asked to strip text from a field and convert it to an int, this works successfully. But now, I would like to do an INNER JOIN on this new value.

So I have this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(accountingTab.id, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', accountingTab.id), 999)) 
AS 'memId',  userDetails.title, userDetails.lname 
FROM accountingTab INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, title, first, last FROM memDetTab) AS userDetails ON memID = userDetails.id
```

And then I get the Invalid Column Name `memID` error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do this, you have design problems.  If you're able, I would suggest you need to refactor your table or relationships.

Comment: The original relationship is with a completely separate table and that table in time has lost information so the next best table is this accounting table :(

Comment: Perhaps you can regenerate a key field from the id field, and/or split the accountingTab.id field into components which can be assembled into the original id field?

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go, I'd rather do that then mess with this.

Comment: For those who voted this answer down: sometimes the answer a person needs or wants to hear is "you shouldn't be doing this, try this other thing instead."

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but keep in mind that sometimes a person is working with a database in a situation where refactoring the datamodel is not feasible. There are a ton of "valid" yet "offensive" reasons for this. Timeschedules, intrateam politics, sheer weight of the code. Your point is valid, of course, but you might consider answering the specific question in addition to making your point.

Comment: @jaydel Yes, I agree, but the fact that the situation may or may not allow refactoring of the database does not mean it is not a valid answer, unless the question provided context to indicate it.

I was not making any particular point - this is, in fact, what I would have done in his situation, if the option were available.

Comment: ...not to mention that the person who asked the question seemed to feel this was a valid and acceptable answer.  I would think he or she should be the arbiter of whether or not this answer was useful and valid for his question.

Comment: Yeah, when this question showed up as the first hit on google, I was SO glad to see the answer was that I have design problems and should refactor my table. TRULY a helpful answer. Thank you SO much.

Comment: @chiliNUT My sarcasm detector is disabled.

Answer (score 6):

You can either repeat the whole expression or reverse your join:

```
SELECT *
FROM memDetTab
    JOIN (SELECT CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(accountingTab.id, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', accountingTab.id), 999)) AS 'memId', userDetails.title, userDetails.lname
FROM accountingTab) subquery
    ON subquery.memID = memDetTab.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea :) It helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of memId, repeat the whole expression.